# Between X with Y

Tags: prepositions

I have recently come across a strange phrase and wanted to know if it might be correct.

> A comparison between X with Y

The `with` in this sentence feels very strange.

thanks for helping me out.

The full sentence:

> For example, a topic could be X, or Y, or a comparison between X with Y, or the causal relation between X and Y, etc.

It literally says X and Y. The full sentence I gave, is exactly what is written in the book.

Comment: It should be 'between X and Y'

Comment: @CinCout I would have said so too. But it was printed in a proper book, which was enough to make me doubt.

Comment: "Proper books" can have mistakes in them.

Comment: it's an error. x and y is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the author (or editor) of the book was confused between these usages:

1. Comparison of X to Y
2. Comparison of X with Y
3. Comparison between X and Y

1 is preferred in American English; 1 and 2 are equally common in British English; 3 is standard in both.

[Compare with or to](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824090532/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/compare-with-or-compare-to)

[Comparison](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comparison)

Comment: The first between is a mistake and should be 'of'. The second between is OK.